# Преобразовать все теги, которые не включены в белый список

Tags: php, tinymce

возникла проблема с редактором TinyMCE, точнее с его выходными данными.
Сам редактор пропускает теги, которые написаны через f12, ну это не важно, я не могу понять, как обрезать теги и атрибуты с помощью htmlentities и не обрезать теги из белого списка. К примеру есть строка

```
$_POST['text'] = '<div style="width: 3000px; text-align: center;"><a onmouseout="alert(1)">XSS</a></';
//И нужно преобразовать width: 3000px; и onmouseout="alert(1)" или удалить их.
```

Как можно так сделать?

Comment: `strip_tags` имеется для белого списка.

Comment: @teran Он удаляет и все атрибуты, в том числе и text-align

Comment: Оно вообще атрибуты не трогает, по-моему.

Comment: Используйте поиск по `stackoverflow` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026096/remove-all-attributes-from-an-html-tag